# IIS Web App Deploy - Azure DevOps Release task deploying all the files present in wwwroot

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying out a release via Azure DevOps. Below is how my screenshot of **IIS WebApp Manage** task.
[image]

Below is my **IIS Web App Deploy** task:

[image]

My artifacts, i.e., the zip file contains only the folder named **package**.

But, still, everything present under wwwroot folder gets deployed to the new web app.

Below is the screenshot of my wwwroot directory:[image]

and thus below are the contents shown under IIS for my newly created website:

[image]

I don't expect Verify2WebServiceSSL to be present here as it is not part of the .zip artifacts.

Comment: Not clear for me: have you created Verify2WebServiceSSL in the past? If you don't need it anymore, why don't you delete it?

Comment: Well, I need it, it's another site I want to host on the same server. I just don't need it under VerifyAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is setting the root of the website to .\wwwroot, so all other files in .\wwwroot are showing in IIS as part of the website.

Try Updating the following to give your VerifyAPI its own folder and clean it during a deployment.

### IIS Web App Manage:

#### IISWebsite

Physical path: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\VerifyAPI

### IIS Web App Deploy

#### Advance Deployment Options

Check 'Remove Addition Files at Destination'